# Combinatorial Proof of Real Analysis Identity

Tags: co.combinatorics

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-fracn-1n-prod-i-1nai-sum-k-1) question, a proof using real analysis is given of the following identity $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)!}{n \prod_{i=1}^{n} (a+i)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a+k)^{2}}$$

Is there a combinatorial proof of this identity? If so, does the proof require that $a$ be a natural number?

Comment: Very good question! I'm also wondering if there are any known obstructions for an infinite-series identity to have a combinatorial proof. (Which means either a "finite partial sums" version or a "generating functions" version.)

Comment: You really mean "direct" instead of "combinatorial". It is a popular belief that elegant formulas must have a combinatorial proof, rather unsupported by the evidence. Negative examples include http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/ and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16129/

Comment: I believe that this identity is a limit of a finite sum that can be proved using the WZ method. Whether that makes it combinatorial is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7):

The proof below is a WZ method proof.

The pair of functions$G(n,k) = \dfrac{(1)_n}{(k+x+1)_n} \, \dfrac{1}{n^2}, \quad$
$F(n,k) = \dfrac{(1)_n}{(k+x+1)_n} \, \dfrac{1}{(k+x+1)n}$

is a WZ (Wilf and Zeilberger) pair. That is $\, G(n,k+1)-G(n,k) = F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)$.

WZ-pairs are gems because of their interesting properties. For example if $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} F(n,k)=0, \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} G(n,k)=0.$$

Wilf and Zeilberger proved that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} G(n,0) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} F(1, k-1).$$

The pair of functions that we are considering satisfies these conditions. Hence

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1)_n}{n^2(x+1)_n} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+x)^2},$$ which is the identity we wanted to prove.

NOTE: With $(a)_n$ we mean the rising factorial.