# Combinatorial proof of Catalan's identity

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs, combinatorial-identities

Consider the problem of tiling a board of length $n$ with squares of size $1×1$ and dominoes of size $1×2$, Let's denote $f_n$ to be the number of ways to tile this so-called ($n$)-board.Then $f_n=F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the nth [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Now the question is as follows:

> Is there any combinatorial way to prove Catalan's identity which states:
>   $$F_{n}^2-F_{n-r}F_{n+r}=(-1)^{n-r}F_r^2$$

---

It's easy to prove this identity using induction or using a more generalized form of that which is indeed Vajda's identity.

Cassini's identity (a special case of Catalan's identity ) has been proved using combinatorial interpretation in a few books, but I've never seen any combinatorial proof of this one.

Comment: "Vajda's identity" is really Tagiuri's identity: A. Tagiuri, Di alcune successioni ricorrenti a termini interi e positivi, Periodico di Matematica 16 (1900–1901), 1–12. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356391/is-there-a-name-for-this-fibonacci-identity.

Answer (score 6):

I always believed that [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/how-can-64-65) combined with [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) is the most visually appealing proof of the identity.  You can also think of it as a bijective proof, if you allow "geometric bijections", cf. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16129/is-there-a-combinatorial-proof-of-cauchy-schwarz/16135#16135).

Answer (score 5):

The method used to prove Example 2.7 [here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Jenne.pdf) (which also appears in the book by Benjamin and Quinn) easily extends to give a combinatorial proof of Catalan's identity.

Comment: Yes, I remember being fond of this method, since the time I saw it. But I also think, much before I read the method from the book, I saw a method closely related to it (if not exactly identical to the method described in the book) to prove some similar types of identities in a paper published by Fibonacci quarterly, but I never found it again (or may have overlooked it).

Answer (score 2):

This would not be a combinatorial proof but you may take it as an alternative method. I'm referring to the method of condensation for determinants as illustrated in [this joint paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6511.pdf). See pages 10-11.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply interpret both $F_n^2$ and $F_{n-r}F_{n+r}$ as the numbers of domino tylings of $2\times (2n-2)$ rectangle with additional restrictions --- vertical cuts on place $n$ (restriction 1) or $n-r$ (restriction 2), and subtract: "tylings with restriction 1" minus "tylings with restriction 2"="tylings with restriction 1 but not 2" minus "tylings with restrictions 2 but not 1". The illustration:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have my copy in front of me, but I am almost positive that a combinatorial proof of this identity appears in the first chapter of *Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof*.